# Using ASP.NET WebService with javascript

Tags: asp.net, ajax, linq, web-services

I have this code in my project:

```
var UI =
{
  Layouts:
  {
    ShowLayoutSettings: function(pid, lid) {
        My.PageServices.GetPageLayout(lid, pid, UI.Layouts._onShowLayoutSettings);
    },
    _onShowLayoutSettings: function(obj) {
            alert(obj.ID);
  }
  }
}
```

and in my asp.net project a web service named PageServices:

```
namespace My
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class PageServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public PageServices()
        {
        }
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = true)]
        [GenerateScriptType(typeof(PageLayout))]
        public PageLayout GetPageLayout(string lid, int pid)
        {
            if (!SystemModel.UserManager.HasLogin())
                return null;
            var o = SystemModel.Layouts.GetPageLayout(pid);
            o.Tag = lid;
            return o;
        }
    }
}
```

I should mention that my PageLayout class is a linq class and it's serialization mode is Unidirectional.

and finally a anchor link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="UI.Layouts.ShowLayoutSettings(5,2);">Test</a>
```

My problem is it is correct and sends ajax request to my service when I click this link and my service returns the object as needed, but it does not fire _onShowLayoutSettings as the call back function for this request.

I tested this work when I create a web servive which just returns and String object, and it was all correct, but I don't know why for my PageLayout object, it's not correct.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but it's very hard, I wrote a JavaScriptConverter named PageLayoutJavaScriptConverter like this:

```
public class PageLayoutJavaScriptConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new Type[] { typeof(PageLayout) };
        }
    }
    public override object Deserialize(
        IDictionary<string, object> dictionary,
        Type type,
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(
        object obj,
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        PageLayout e = obj as PageLayout;
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (e != null)
        {
            result.Add("ID", e.ID);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and add this tag to web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
    <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization>
            <converters>
                <add name="PageLayoutJavaScriptConverter" type="WebApp.Code.PageLayoutJavaScriptConverter"/>
            </converters>
        </jsonSerialization>
    </webServices>
    <scriptResourceHandler enableCaching="true" enableCompression="true"/>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

and all was correct.

I have a question, Isn't any other simpler way to do this work?

Comment: yes, I'm surprised your code before this converter doesn't work.  I've had similar working before.  This seems like overkill. But well done for getting something working

Answer (score 1):

if it worked with returning a string, then you probably need to tell the ajax extension to create javascript code for the object you're trying to return.  Add an attribute above your webmethod

```
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(PageLayout))]
```

where PageLayout is the name of the class the GetPageLayout returns

Comment: I thought when I do this it will do correct, but it does not. I saw the HTMl source code and saw this code: 

var gtc = Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy._generateTypedConstructor;
Type.registerNamespace('DALEntities');
if (typeof(DALEntities.PageLayout) === 'undefined') {
DALEntities.PageLayout=gtc("DALEntities.PageLayout");
DALEntities.PageLayout.registerClass('DALEntities.PageLayout');
}
//]]>
</script>

Comment: Ok i still think putting that attribute in there is in the right direction.  If its still not working, can you edit your post to add the attribute

Comment: A long shot, but could it be that you've got the extra comma (,) after your definition of _onShowLayoutSettings().   some browsers (IE i think) won't like that.  I think FF might be more forgiving

Comment: I did correct it, I was wrong in the code, extra comma was because of it was among other functions, and in my test last function does not have this comma.